# Adding elements to an array java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, addition, shift

Hello I was wondering on how write a method to add and remove objects from an array of objects in java. I am **not allowed to use any of java's built in abstract data structures to do this such as array list or vectors ect.** . The list of cars is intially empty but newCar- the new Car object to add to this collection 
position - the position in this CarCollection where car will be inserted 
Preconditions:
This CarCollection object has been instantiated and 1 < position < items_currently_in_list + 1. The number of car objects in this Menu is less than maxCarsPossible.

Postcondition:
The new car is now stored at the desired position in the collection. All carthat were originally in positions greater than or equal to position are moved back one position. (Ex: If there are 5 cars in a collecion, positions 1-5, and you insert a new car at position 4, the new card will now be at position 4, the car that was at position 4 will be moved to position 5, and the car that was at position 5 will be moved to position 6).

```
public class CarCollection {

    private Car[] collection;
    final int maxCarsPossible = 100;

    public CarCollection()
    {
        collection = new Car[0];

    }

    public void addCar(Car newCar,int position)
    {

        for(int i =0; i < collection.length; i++)
        {
            if(collection.length+1>=position&&position>=1)
            {
                i = position;
                collection[i] = newCar;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to add/remove an element to the array (as in your title), or create a new array which is copy of the old one with element added/removed?

Comment: @AdrianShum brings up a good question, this is very important to determine the kind of solution you need.

Making a copy of the array would "remove" the data. 

I do see one problem in your constructor though; you are making the array size 0 right off the bat. This is probably not what you intended.

Also, your if-statement is really confusing, try breaking it apart, there is no harm in using nested if-statements if it improves clarity.

Comment: collection.length + 1? When would you ever be stepping over the bounds of your array? This condition will always be true because of the way your for loop is designed. You should never be looking over the bounds of the array.

Comment: the biggest problem I think is OP haven't asked any question...

Comment: @AdrianShum   i need to add a car object into the current array without losing anyof the previous data , so the method essentially needs add an element in any given position in the array and shift what ever element is in that position to the next index so if a car is in position 4 and i wish to add a new car to position 4 the method should add the new car and push the old car to position 5 if that makes sense . I am having trouble writing this method out . For now all i need to do is focus on adding new elements to the array

Comment: @n94pro One thing you need to be aware of: Array size in Java is not dynamic.  If you allocated a `new Car[0]`, then it can only store 0 cars.  It cannot be extended.   Another thing is, learn to ask.  Tell us clearly what your problem is.  Quoting your homework and throwing out some code is NOT properly asking questions

Comment: @n94pro If you are adding elements to the array you need to be aware of the bounds. I get the idea from your code above that you haven't considered that pushing data into your array many times will cause an out-of-bounds error. How are you supposed to deal with data that is being pushed over the end of the array?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend storing another array called oldCarCollection, and just resetting and updating that every time a new car is added. For example, in your addCar method,

```
public void addCar(Car carToAdd) {
    cars = new Car[oldCars.length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
        if (i == oldCars.length) {
            // If we're done transferring from old cars.
            cars[i] = carToAdd;
        } else {
            // Transfer from old cars
            cars[i] = oldCars[i];
        }
    }
    // Update oldCars
    oldCars = new Car[cars.length];
    System.arraycopy(cars, 0, oldCars, 0, oldCars.length);
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it using the set parameters in the method header? using the object and int for inserting in a specific position?

Comment: What you could do is declare String[] cars and String[] oldCars at the top of the class (that's what I did in that example).

Comment: the car objects have multiple values string ints double arrays stored in them ect

Comment: I changed it to a better way of using it. The car you want to add goes in as a parameter in the method, and the method adds it in after making the array size bigger and adding the old cars.